# Failed loading cafile stream in "file_get_contents()"?

Tags: php, google-geocoding-api

I was trying to get json data from google geocoding api. However the php warning shows some error about "failed loading cafile stream"

Here is my code:

```
$apiKey  = 'apikey';
$address = urlencode( '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043' 
);
$url     = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= 
    {$address}key={apiKey}";
$resp    = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ), true );
echo $url;

$lat    = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] ?? '';
$long   = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] ?? '';
```

Here is the error:

```
PHP Warning:  failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca- 
bundle.crt' in C:\Users\1\Desktop\test.php on line 7

Warning: failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca- 
bundle.crt' in C:\Users\1\Desktop\test.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in 
C:\Users\1\Desktop\test.php on line 7

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in 
C:\Users\1\Desktop\test.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  
file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
address=1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy%2C+Mountain+Vi
ew%2C+CA+94043key={apiKey}): failed to open stream: operation failed in 
C:\Users\1\Desktop\test.php on line 7

Warning: 
file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
address=1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy%2C+Mountain+View%2C
+CA+94043key={apiKey}): failed to open stream: operation failed in 
C:\Users\1\Desktop\test.php on line 7
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
address=1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy%2C+Mountain+View%2C+CA+94043key={apiKey}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This error occurs when the **curl.cainfo** and **openssl.cafile** config properties of your php.ini file do not target any valid certificate that allow you to create connection with ssl as they will be invalid.

This is occurs when calling request to external servers by using CURL  as example.

You have to donwload the *casert.pem* from the link [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

And  place the certification file in the path :

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem

After, check the php.ini on the config key named : **curl.cainfo** and **openssl.cafile** and make this config

example :

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile = "‪C:\xampp\apache\bin\cacert.pem"
```

Comment: I think you mean `openssl.cafile` in the second line.

Comment: I was facing same problem with SoapClient.  above solution working fine with xampp ( windows )

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mohammed Yassine CHABLI's anwser. Changing the filename and the path in the php.ini did not solve it for me.

I had to rename the 'cacert.pem' to 'curl-ca-bundle.crt' to make it work.

Comment: perhaps restarting apache on xampp control panel will do after the php.ini changes

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS users `brew install openssl` solved this for me

Answer (score 0):

You just have to go to your ROUTE C: \ xampp \ perl \ vendor \ lib \ Mozilla \ CA
and copy the file called cacert.pem

Then enter your php.ini file and in [curl] paste the following path C: \ xampp \ perl \ vendor \ lib \ Mozilla \ CA \ cacert.pem
--curl.cainfo="C: \ xampp \ perl \ vendor \ lib \ Mozilla \ CA \ cacert.pem"

you will do the same in [openssl]
--openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem"

Comment: Always use code formatting. It will give better readability.